# FSM 4x7 segment displays Verilog

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, 7segmentdisplay

I got problem getting around Verilog. I am trying to create a FSM that displays numbers on one of the displays and on the next state to display a string. I did make the string to be displayed separately and the number separately in 2 projects, but I am getting errors when I try to combine it. What I did was to set an always@ loop and place in there a flag in if else statement with two switch cases but I got error saying that is preferable to get rid of the combinatorial logic loop. Is there any way I can combine both functionalities?

Ok, I will post some code, but the main picture is that I have a master state machine and then I got another state machine. I use the other state machine as input to the 7segment display for a single number. But in a different state of the master state machine I have to display a message on the 4 7segment displays. What I got now is: 
Here I used CLK in order to make the message

```
always@(BIN_IN or CLK) begin
if(FAIL==1) begin
     case(state)
           left:
           begin
               HEX_OUT [6:0] <= F;
               SEG_SELECT_OUT <= 4'b0111;
               state <= midleft;
           end
           midleft:
           begin
               HEX_OUT [6:0] <= A;
               SEG_SELECT_OUT <= 4'b1011;
               state <= midright;
           end
//same for the rest
end
else begin  
case (BIN_IN)
4'h0 : begin
    HEX_OUT [6:0] <= 7'b1000000;
    SEG_SELECT_OUT <= 4'b0111;
end
//same logic for the other cases
```

Thanks

Comment: Your are inferring combinational logic with `always@(BIN_IN or CLK)`, and RTL behavior will not match synthesized gates. At minimum, you need to change it to `always@(posedge CLK)` to make it synchronous.

Comment: You can change anode selection at full clock speed. There is a Fmax defined by your display -> lookup in the data sheet. This design is not synchronous.

Comment: @Paebbels , The whole project consists of a top module and 6 sub modules to the top. So everything is nested and it now looks complicated. So I have a master state machine and a maze machine. When I enter lets say state 3 of the master I go to the maze machine and then I have to finish it and pass the finished result to the master. Also I have to count 30 sec in which I have to complete the maze, If I cannot I have to display message

Comment: I don't really know how this might work in the 7segment module as In once case it has to change the numbers and in the other it has to use all the segments to display a message .

Answer (score 1):

I think i understand your problem , i had similar problem when starting making circuits in HDL (verilog or VHDL) and coming from programming C++ , python or other languages.

What you need to understand is that in verilog , your variables represent wires(bits) or group of wires (vectors).... so you cant assign same variable as output from 2 parts of your circuit... this would be as weird as having a lamp with 2 plugs ...

Just "somehow" put both machines in same process and it will work.